# Change of Windows display language fails for Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, language, display-settings

I get error messages when installing a language pack on Windows 10 in order to change the Windows display language.

When I go through settings -> Language -> Options I get the message 'Connect to the internet to check for language packs', however the computer is connected tot the internet... [image: connect to internet]

Then when I try a manual install through Run -> lpksetup with a langeage pack file downloaded [here](http://www.leongiuseppe.altervista.org/Jblog/consulenza/16-assistenza-software/188-windows-10-language-packs-direct-download-links) I get message langage cannot be installed on your computer.[image: language cannot be installed]

Moreover when i look under deinstall in lpksetup it shows that German is still system language [image: German system language]although that language was deleted in the language settings window: [image]

The OS is Windows 10 Home 64-bit (upgraded from Windows 7). Originally the system was installed with German language settings. Now I want to change that to Dutch. Currently the display language is mostly English, with some German and some Dutch...

From Windows Updates the .NET Framework 4.8 Language Packs for Windows 10 was succesfully installed: [image]

(Probably as a consequence of the described issue) Dutch cannot be set as the Windows display language in the Language settings window.

Any ideas as to what the problem is and how to solve?

Comment: As of several years ago you can only install languages within the Settings application on Windows 10.  Why are you trying to do it through Control Panel and lpksetup? Language packs for .NET have little to do with the language packs installed for Windows

Comment: MUI packages cant be used for home, reinstall windows with the correct language

Comment: I tried lpksetup because it didn't work through the language settings application (message 'Connect to the internet to check for language packs', see question). If you know how to solve that issue then I would love to continue through the settings app.

Comment: I read somewhere (can't find the page anymore...) that reïnstalling windows is not necessery in order to change the Windows display language. Is that true only for other versions of Windows 10 then the Home version?

Comment: It’s only necessary if you actually have Windows 10 Home Single Language installed.  Which is likely if your unable to install additional languages through Settings.

Comment: Well the English language pack could be installed, the Dutch LP couldn't...

Comment: Make sure you are not using the "Single Language" edition. Check with: `slmgr.vbs -dli`